# Each of the individual kubernetes containers to be made accessible from Internet - is it possible?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm considering kubernetes as a platform for my application. I will launch multiple StatefulSets, each containing up to, say, 32 containers. kubernetes cluster will contain a few nodes, and each node will be assigned for e.g. 32+ external IP addresses.

My application requires that clients running somewhere on the internet to be able to reach each individual server instance via a static IP address and port for client-based load balancing and failover. Servers can come up and die from tie to time, but server address should be stable while the server is running.

To summarise in simple words I would like to be able to access my containers from Internet like this:

- StatefulSet 1:

  - container 1: node1.domain.com:1000
  - container 2: node2.domain.com:1000
- StatefulSet 2:

  - container 1: node1.domain.com:1001
  - container 2: node2.domain.com:1001
- StatefulSet 3:

  - container 1: node2.domain.com:1002
  - container 2: node3.domain.com:1002

Is this something that is possible to achieve with kubernetes? If so, could you provide a hint how and reference to relevant kubernetes documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're tied to a `StatefulSet`? Sounds more like a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) to me. If you want to stick with `StatefulSet`, just use the container/host port parameters in your `container` spec.

Example, run the apps `overflow-foo`, `overflow-bar`, `overflow-baz` each on their own ports on every node matching your selector criteria in the cluster.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: overflow-app
  labels:
    app: overflow-app-agent
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: overflow-app
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      hostIPC: true
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - image: overflow-foo:latest
        name: overflow-bar
        command: [ "bash", "-c", "run.sh" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1000
          hostPort: 1000
      - image: overflow-bar:latest
        name: overflow-bar
        command: [ "bash", "-c", "run.sh" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1001
          hostPort: 1001
      - image: overflow-baz:latest
        name: overflow-baz
        command: [ "bash", "-c", "run.sh" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1002
          hostPort: 1002
```

Comment: Hm, yes, probably this is what I need in terms of how it can be executed. I have two follow up questions. 
1) I need the containers to be able to communicate with each other via a stable network id, use a stable storage and scale on demand. I was looking on StatefulSet because it provides exactly this feature.
2) If I specify hostPort vs hostNetwork option in a template, which IP it will be eventually bound to? E.g.I might have just a few kubernetes nodes, but many containers in the same Set and many external IP addresses. And I need for each node to be bound to some external IP and port.

Comment: This is starting to sound dangerously like "do my homework for me". Hate to say RTFM but... Read docker, kubernetes and openshift docs. You questions will be answered in most of the "getting started" docs.

Comment: 1) Containers will all assume IP/networkID of their host when deployed this way.
2) This question doesn't make sense... `hostnetwork` and `hostPort`  do two separate things. `hostNetwork` gives the pod full access to the node network. Sounds to me like it only needs the port. Only expose the port if that's all you need.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to force someone to do my work. Networking subject is not clearly documented in kubernetes. It give a few typical scenarios but still very limited. Thus it is not clear what exactly is possible to achieve with kubernetes. 
The purpose of this question is to clarify kubernetes networking capabilities and fill in the docs gap. An expert advice, before diving into detailed research and experiments, can save precious time, especially in case kubernetes does not the kind of requirements I have.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `Services` for exposure of your `StatefulSets`. You would define a single service per Stateful Set and expose it to the outside world with a `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`. A `NodePort` is available to address on every `Node` in the cluster and a LoadBalancer would be a single point of entry that also balances the load to the different `PODs` of your StatefulSet. For more information you can read the official docs for [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), especially the sections for [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) and [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer).

One additional note - The NodePort uses a port range 30000-32767 by default, but you can change it with the cluster parameter `service-node-port-range`. See [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/).